# Python - Unpacking a DAT file with Hex values and Incompletely

Tags: python, struct, binaryfiles, sql-loader

I am trying to unpack a binary file (file.dat) but it is just unpacking one single row while it has more than 800, also when I print the result of struct.unpack(), the string field is giving me lots of HEX values, is there a way to remove those Hex values and other unwanted characters (like 'N')? I have the actual following code:

```
with open(f'file.dat', mode="rb") as binFile:
    binData = binFile.read(26)
    data = struct.unpack('i22s', binData)
    print(data)

binFile.close()
```

It gives me the following result, the integer value is correct but the string needs to be only 'PROV111'.  Also as you can see it reads only one record:

```
(1000000054, b'N\x07\x00PROV111\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')
```

Comment: Without a record specification, it looks like `\x07\x00` is a little-endian length of string and you could post-process to read the following string.  Also, your `binFile.close()` is redundant when using a `with`.  If you can, give a larger sample of the raw data and the specification of the record.

Comment: If you think you have 800 rows of the same format, then surely you understand you need to loop until the read fails.  If you want to post the file somewhere, some of us can take a look.

Comment: I submitted it into a google drive link: 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hHNQbYVpnJKGG-x2cKuCrsukbiOh41lU/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

The answers are already in the comments, but let's make them more explicit.

You are reading a standard size (i.e. 32 bits) signed `int` followed by a 22 char string, but your data are in a different format: after the intial `int` you have a 'N' (you may know why), a short (16 bits) signed `int` which represents the actual string lenght, and finally your string, zero-padded.

So you should read your struct and then extract the actual string with something like:

```
#the format string looks for an int, a dummy char, a short int, the string
number, dummy, str_len, padded_str = struct.unpack('ish19s', binData)
true_str = padded_str[:str_len]
print(number, true_str)
```

And yes, of course you should loop until EOF to read all the bytes chunks in your file.